# How make axios request (Negotiate/SPNEGO token)?

Tags: go, vue.js, active-directory, axios, kerberos

From `frontend` application (Vue.js) I make axios (ajax) request to the URL of `backend` application (Golang) which works with **Kerberos**. I need to return information about the employee when frontend application makes GET request to the route of backend application.

Inside frontend application I make such axios request:

```
axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true})
```

Inside backend application I set CORS options like that:

```
headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})
origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
credentials := handlers.AllowCredentials() // true
```

Right now client application raise `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` error when I make axios request. Everythink works fine only if I make request from browser.

In the log of the backend application I see such header information when I make request from browser:

```
map[Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36] Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Accept-Language:[ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7] Connection:[keep-alive] Cache-Control:[max-age=0]]
map[Connection:[keep-alive] Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36] Accept-Language:[ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7] Cache-Control:[max-age=0] Authorization:[Negotiate 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] Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate]]
```

As you can see browser somehow generate SPNEGO (Negotiate) token and set it to header automatically. I can't understand how I can make the same result via axios request. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: axios third  argument can be used for headers: `axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true},{   headers: {'Negotiate': 'oi4u234p5oiu34po'}   })`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki hello! Where did you get this token value? As I understand this token which you set in Negotiate is dynamic, right?

Comment: Yes it's dynamic, I just gave you a tip for how to add a header to axios request

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki do you have any ideas how to generate that token?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea